# How to manage patching/reboot of secondary node to prevent auto failover when file share is unstable?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, sql-server-2019

In a 2 node FCI cluster with file share witness, assuming the file share is unstable (inaccessible) due to network issues.

Case 1:
File share is down (inaccessible) and during this time I patch/reboot node 2. If the cluster has allocated the voting power to node 1 (dynamic quorum) then all ok. If it has given the voting power to node 2 (dynamic quorum) then the cluster will fail at this point.

Case 2:
Suppose I restart node 2. At this point the cluster will auto set the vote of file share to 0 (dynamic witness). During that moment if the file share becomes unstable (inaccessible) then the cluster will remain healthy.

Please correct me if case 1 and 2 are correct understanding.

And how do I prevent the auto failover? For example- is there some setting I can do in the wsfc manager to make sure it won't failover.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to mess with wsfc configurations when you deal with AG.
If you do not want automatic failover, then you need to change the failover configuration inside of your AG (switch from auto failover to manual failover) before you do your patching.

As mentioned in another thread, you should be looking at your witness issue an not trying to go around it.

If your issue is with network, then try to have your witness set somewhere else (it could be in the cloud).

Comment: Assuming node 1 is is Is active node, Is it true that if the witness goes down, then dynamic quorum can randomly assign the vote to either node 1 or node 2? And that if it happens to give the vote power to node 2 and someone restarts node 2 then the entire cluster goes down?